# Java Makes infinity do while loop :/

Tags: java, do-while

I have programmed all night long and I can't find a mistake anymore :/ :/
If intro == 1 or 2 then do this and that.. and if intro != 1 or 2 then ask number again, till the number is 1 or 2... I can't find the mistake :/

```
   do{
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        Scanner scanintro = new Scanner(System.in);
        intro = scanintro.next();
    }while (intro == ("1")|| intro == ("2"));
```

Comment: Your condition is inverted anyway: `while (!intro.equals("1") && !intro.equals("2"));`

Comment: Thank you. i'm stupid xD

Answer (score 5):

```
do{
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    Scanner scanintro = new Scanner(System.in);
    intro = scanintro.nextInt();
} while (intro == 1|| intro == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    Scanner scanintro = new Scanner(System.in);
    intro = scanintro.next();
} while (!intro.equals("1") && !intro.equals("2"));
```

You should use `equals` to compare strings, but its an int(I don't know what the datatype of your intro variable is, but you should change it to an int) so you can check it like this:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    Scanner scanintro = new Scanner(System.in);
    intro = scanintro.next();
} while (intro != 1 || intro != 2);
```

Comment: According to the spec in the question, that condition should be inverted: keep going until that value is either 1 or 2.

Comment: @YCF_L it doesn't actually: what if you enter a non-integer? Then the loop would error out.

Comment: yes @AndyTurner this is correct my mistake

Comment: `!intro.equals("1") || !intro.equals("2")`, which you have currently, is always true.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov correct, changed it!